# Relating co-variant basis of different coordinate systems

Tags: tensors

In page 77 of Introduction to Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces by Pavel Grinfeld, He relates a covariant basis in one coordinate with another. He does it in the following way:

Say that the reference covariant basis is $ Z_i$ and the new basis in a new coordinate system is $Z_{i'}$, then we can define the new basis as derivative of the position vector R:

$$ Z_{i'}  = \frac{ \partial R(Z') } { \partial Z^{i'}}$$

Now, the part which confuses me is the one he says right after:

$$ R(Z') = R(Z(Z') )$$

I just can't understand how he got the above identity, I seek a simple explanation of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try example with a concrete example. Suppose we had a function,

$$ f(r,\theta) = r \sin \theta$$

Then, in Cartesian we could write,

$$ f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \sin \tan^{-1}( \frac{y}{x} )$$

But, in the above function if we substituted $x=r \cos \theta$ and $y= r \sin \theta$, we'd have:

$$ f \big(x(r,\theta), y(r,\theta) \big) = r \sin \theta$$

Meaning,

$$ f(r,\theta) := f \big(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta) \big)$$

The actual topic is about Chart transition maps, I found this [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7G4SqIboeig&list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_) to be of aid, it's about GR but about lecture-5 or 6, transition maps are discussed.

Answer (score 0):

He explains it in his book step-by-step right after equation $(6,10),$ and would be the answer to the question from another user that has been linked to this one:

$${\bf Z_{i'}}=\frac{\partial \vec R(Z')}{\partial Z^{i'}}$$

> The function $\vec R(Z')$ gives the position vector $\vec R$ as a function of the coordinates $Z^{i'}.$ The following is the critical step from which the ultimate relationship is derived. The function $\vec R(Z')$ can also be constructed by substituting $Z^i(Z^{'})$ — the expression for the unprimed coordinates in terms of the primed coordinates— into $\vec R(Z)$ that is the function that gives the position vector $\vec R$ as a function of the unprimed coordinates $Z^i$:

$$\vec R(Z')=\vec R(Z(Z'))$$

Comment: O man I really wished my answer helped ;-;. One thing it should actually be Z(Z'(Z)) I believe